# Se necesita tener compiler para trabajar con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web, xampp, composer

Necesito hacer un aplicacion en web pero necesito primero ambientar el entorno de windows, instale xampp y luego composer, pero me dio un error

> The Composer installer script was not successful [exit code 1].
>   Script Output:
>   The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL: 
>   La operación se completó correctamente.
>   failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy

Voy a trabajar con Laravel, es necesario tenerlo.

El error por el que sale pienso que es porque en el luegar donde estoycuenta con un proxy y lo puse en el exe pero no me deja

Comment: Creo que deberías clarificar la pregunta

Comment: Ya pude lo que hice fue instarlo manualmente, y tenemos que descargar el composer.phar de la pagina oficial de laravel, de ahi tenemos que crear un folder en C: nombrado composer y pegar el .phar y un  archivo .bat el cual debe de contener 
@php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*  
pero debes tener ya xampp instaldo con el php